# Unable to get the cpu and memory usage using process id

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to get the process id in PID and then get the cpu and memory usage with all the process id that the grep command has listed but I am facing an error. Any help would be appreciated

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=`ps -eaf | grep firefox | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
usage= `ps -p $PID -o %cpu,%mem`
```

error:

```
error: process ID list syntax error

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do one at a time

```
#!/bin/bash
for PID in `ps -eaf | grep firefox | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` ; do
    usage=`ps -p $PID -o %cpu,%mem`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when firefox is not running: the PID does not exist and you get following behaviour:

```
Prompt>ps -p -o %cpu,%mem // as firefox does not run, $PID is empty
error: process ID list syntax error

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

Comment: It is getting the process id the only issue is that the usage command need one pid at a time so I need to figure out the logic for that, Any suggestion that you can provide?

Comment: In case you have more PIDs, causing the issue, you might opt for a `for each` loop, for which you can find ample examples on the internet, like [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-foreach-loop-examples-for-linux-unix/).

Answer (score 0):

The suggested command to get `csv` list of pid `pgrep -d, -f firefox` .

Or collect pids_list into variable:

```
pid_list=$(pgrep -d, -f firefox)
```

Now use `ps` command to extract information about `$pid_list`

```
ps -p $pid_list -o %cpu,%mem
```

#### Or in one line:

```
ps -p $(pgrep -d, -f firefox) %cpu,%mem
```